# creating a dynamic html select option with perl

Tags: html, perl

The default selected value from the database is not displayed, I also checked the HTML  and does not show the selected value. Can someone give me some insight on where I went wrong. Thanks

```
  my $selected_val = 'selected';
  print "<select>";
  if ($auto_flag eq 'Y'){
        $selected_val = 'selected';
  }else{
    $selected_val = '';
  }
  if ($auto_flag eq 'N'){
    $selected_val = 'selected';
  }else{
      $selected_val = '';
  }
  print "<option value=\"Y\" $selected_val >Yes</option>";
  print "<option value=\"N\" $selected_val >No</option>";

  print "</select>";
```

Answer (score 5):

You should be using separate variable names for Y/N

```
my $selected_y = '';
my $selected_n = '';
if ($auto_flag eq 'Y'){
    $selected_y = 'selected';
}
elsif ($auto_flag eq 'N'){
    $selected_n = 'selected';
}
print "<option value=\"Y\" $selected_y >Yes</option>";
print "<option value=\"N\" $selected_n >No</option>";
```